# How to os.walk a mapped network drive

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use os.walk to check all cbz files inside a folder (and sub-folders).  I've tested this on a folder on my C: drive and everything works fine.  However, when running it on a mapped network drive (Q:), it ends immediately with no results.

I've tried using `r"Q:/Multimedia/Comics"` as well as `Q:\\Multimedia\\Comics`, but neither work.

```py
def get_all_file_paths(directory):
    file_paths = []

    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if filepath.startswith('._'):
                pass
            elif filepath.endswith('.cbz'):
                    file_paths.append(filepath)
        return file_paths


def main():
    directory = r"Q:/Multimedia/Comics"
    file_paths = get_all_file_paths(directory)
```

I expect the directory to be iterated through and have the files that match the if and elif statements passed through to "filepath".  Instead the program immediately ends with exit code 0.

Comment: did you try `os.walk(..., followlinks=True)`?

Comment: I just tried that and got the same result.  Starting to think this might not be a code issue after all.  I put some files in another location on the same Q: drive and I'm able to run the program on that folder.  Might be some sort of permissions issue, but I would think I would get an access denied message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found no other solution than mount the drive and access it through the directory I mounted it to.

Hope it helps. Regards.